# Método deserializa y serializa da errores

Tags: java

El `main` devuelve un error en los métodos `serializa` y `deserializa`. Bueno, varios, pero no puedo ponerlos porque es demasiado código y entonces no puedo poner el método `serializa` ni el `deserializa`.

La idea es que, si no existe el fichero, se cree. Una vez sea creado, entre al menú y si hacemos clic en `8`, entre al `case 8`, salga del programa y guarde toda la información que hemos metido en el fichero. Una vez esté guardado, si volvemos a activar el `main`, cargaría los datos que ya tenemos de antes.

Éste es mi código. Intento ahorrar en código pero `serializa` y `deserializa` son métodos largos. He reducido los `case` del menú a 2 para que os hagáis una idea.

Éste es:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File miFichero = new File("PilaDePartes.dat");
    Empresa e = null;
    if (!miFichero.exists()) {
        e = new Empresa();
    } else {
        e = deserializa();
    }
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean salir = false;
    int opcion; // Guardaremos la opcion del usuario

    while (!salir) {
        System.out.println("*********************************************");
        System.out.println("1. Anadir un nuevo parte de trabajo");
        System.out.println("2. Añadir material al parte");
        System.out.println("6. Listar  todas los partes");
        System.out.println("7. Ordenar los partes de trabajo por la fecha del parte de forma ascendente.");
        System.out.println("8. Salir");
        System.out.println("*********************************************");
        System.out.println("Elija una de las opciones");

        opcion = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());

        switch (opcion) {
            case 7:
                Collections.sort(e.getPilaDePartes());
                break;

            case 8:
                salir = true;
                serializa(e);
                entrada.close();
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Solo numeros entre 1 y 10");

        }
    }
}

private static void serializa(Empresa e) {
    FileOutputStream miFos = null;
    ObjectOutputStream miOos = null;
    try {
        String miFichero = "PilaDePartes.dat";

        miFos = new FileOutputStream(miFichero);
        miOos = new ObjectOutputStream(miFos);
        miOos.writeObject(e);
        miOos.close();
        miFos.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GestionDePartes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            miFos.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GestionDePartes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            miOos.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GestionDePartes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

//Deserializamos el Objeto ArrayList desde un fichero
private static Empresa deserializa() {
    FileInputStream miFis = null;
    ObjectInputStream miOis = null;
    Empresa e = null;
    try {
        String miFichero = "PilaDePartes.dat";
        miFis = new FileInputStream(miFichero);
        miOis = new ObjectInputStream(miFis);
        boolean seguir = true;
        while (seguir) {
            try {
                e = (Empresa) miOis.readObject();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GestionDePartes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (EOFException endOfFileException) {
                seguir = false;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GestionDePartes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        miOis.close();
        miFis.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GestionDePartes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            miFis.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GestionDePartes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            miOis.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GestionDePartes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    return e;
}
```

Comment: Aunque quede una pregunta larga, el output de error es necesario para saber qué puede estar fallando.

Comment: El código de la clase `Empresa` también es importante.

Comment: y donde te pongo todo eso?porque si lo pongo en la pregunta me va a decir que tengo demasiado código ya me volvi mono para poneros eso

Comment: @E.Betanzos no se donde ponerte el código de los errores y la clase empresa para que puedas verlo

Comment: Mira como hacer un [mcve]. No necesitas hacer (y postear) todo tu programa completo para que se vea el error; elimina todo lo que no sea necesario de *Empresa* (y del *main*) hasta conseguir el programa mínimo que te dé el mismo error. Y necesitamos el mensaje de error.

Comment: @SJuan76 esa idea es buena si hubiera algo que quitar el problema es que del main como mucho puedo quitar 2 línea y si tengo que añadir toda las línea de error y la clase empresa pues no es muy factible

Comment: @Carlos24345 agrega el código de la clase `Empresa` debajo de todos los métodos que has agregado y la traza de error debajo de todo. De otra forma casi que no podemos ayudarte.

Comment: Me diria que es mucho codigo. pero ya descubrí el error hay que implementar serializable en todas la clases

Answer (score 1):

Según la documentación de Java 7 de [`ObjectInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html),

*"Only objects that support the java.io.Serializable or java.io.Externalizable interface can be read from streams."*

Es decir, solamente los objetos que implementen ya sea o la interfaz `java.io.Serializable` o `java.io.Externalizable` pueden ser leídos.

La buena noticia es que no debes hacer algo complicado, simplemente modificar tu clase de la siguiente manera:

si tienes tu clase original

```
// original
public class miClase {
}
```

solamente le agregas implements y el import

```
// modificada
import java.io.Serializable;
public class miClase implements Serializable {
}
```